# Does a .NET assembly embed any personally identifiable information?

Tags: .net, .net-assembly

I was wondering if a .NET assembly contains any traceble information? I refer to any information that might connect an assembly with the computer it was made on, the person who made it, or maybe the Visual Studio it was made with?

Comment: Grammar: 'Are .NET assemblies traceable?' rather than 'Is .NET assemblies traceable?'

Comment: @Theo you can edit the post!  (though until you get to a certain rep level it has to be approved first)

Comment: I'm not from an english speaking country, so I wouldn't be surprised if my posts contains some spelling and gramma mistakes. I hope you will bear with me

Answer (score 1):

Debug symbols gives away some file structure and AssemblyInfo's give away some meta-data as well. Your strings might matter. The date-of-modification is set. Sometimes semantically equivalent programs (read: small non-logic changes) can give different binary signatures.

Comment: So what your saying is that in theory yes, in practise no?

Comment: @Jacobih Also consider other data which might "leak in" such as the assembly properties (e.g. company name or version) -- even a strong-signed assembly may reflect the sign-key used. In addition to strings, other embedded data, such as GUIDs, etc. may provided a means of "tracing".

Comment: In practise no, but to be sure, run ildasm on it, grep through the output to get strings (they are allocated in the same way accross).